# Unable to download app from app store on Windows 10 Mobile Emulator

Tags: windows-phone, windows, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to download and open an app on a windows 10 emulator from the windows app store but I keep getting a download error.

Error code: 0x803F7003

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Other suggestions say to reset store cache, but not able to find how to do that on a phone.

Screenshot of error..

[image: windows phone error]

Comment: Hi, I have the same error!